# How to include headers from another directory (but not knowing which)

Tags: gcc, makefile, header-files

I am trying to compile module. I can do so by calling make, which calls

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) modules
```

But I want to see preprocessed output, So I am trying to compile manually with `cc -E file.c`. The problem is, It cannot see header `<linux/init.h>`:

```
fatal error: linux/init.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/init.h>
```

I have notice, when make is called, it first enter this dir `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-38-generic`, There is probably the header, but I do not know where. I have tried `gcc -E -I'/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-38-generic file.c`, but still the same error. So how is possible to include kernel headers (which `<linux/init.h> is`) in user mode - that is how to include headers from another dir?

PS: as @uzsolt in comments suggested, I add `include` to the end of path: `gcc -I /usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-38-generic/include`. But then another header is missing - `<asm/linkage.h>`, and again - I have no clue in what dir this header is.

Comment: Did you find `linux/init.h`? https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=linux%2Finit.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=eoan&arch=any - I think you should use `gcc -I /usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-38-generic/include` (notice the tailing `include`).

Comment: Then another file missing, After few lines of preprocessed text: `<asm/linkage.h>` - no such file or dir. I do not know, where to look for this header

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `find` command: `find /usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-38-generic -name MISSED_FILE`.

I don't know your linux distribution but I think you should add these parameters to `gcc`:

```
-I/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-38-generic/include -I/usr/src/linux-aws-headers-5.3.0-1003/arch/x86/include/
```